# Exiting the JVM on Error

Tags: jvm

I am working on this application that requires loading of native library. the loading of the class that initiates the loading of the native library is running on a different thread from the main thread.
When an error occurs (an error is thrown), i would expect that the vm terminates, but in this case it does not. certainly when i cant load the native library, i must not continue, because thats the core of the application.
I assume my application is not terminating because the main thread starts at least 3 threads. the connection thread-that listens if a gadget has been connected and then informs the listener that it has been connected or disconnected, and other resource management threads.

How would i end my application when the jls says that the application should not try to catch errors?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question properly, I'll need to know more information about the other threads that you spawned.  Can they be set to daemon-type threads?  If not, how do you normally gracefully exit those threads?

Here's a brute-force way (inside the thread that loads the native library):

```
try {
    methodToLoadLibrary();
    doWhatYouNeedToDo();
} finally {
    System.exit(1);
}
```

but this assumes that you'll be exiting the entire process when this thread terminates.

If you have a method which can be called to make the threads terminate gracefully, you can replace the `System.exit(1);` call with this:

```
Collection<Stoppable> sList;
for(Stoppable s : sList) {
    s.stop();
}
```

where `Stoppable` is the interface for communicating that you want a graceful shutdown on those threads.

There are also less-clean ways like calling `Thread.stop` on the other threads.